# Discord with Python: Sending embeds to specific channels given by user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

Please check the following demo:

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages= True)
async def quickembed(ctx, *,msg):
    em = discord.Embed(description=f'{msg}', color=discord.Color.green())  
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the channel a required argument and then send it there, like this:

```py
@bot.command() 
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages= True) 
async def quickembed(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, * , msg): 
    em = discord.Embed(description=f'{msg}', color=discord.Color.green())
    await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Comment: Can you tell me about same thing for colour

Comment: Would be the exact same thing except you might be better off using hex colour codes for that input